# Ext JS 4.0.7 Store with LocalStorage Proxy

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an Store and a LocalStorage Proxy. The Store is connected to gridpanel. In the toolbar of the gridpanel is a button "remove all". This button is connected to an controller action as follows:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("Conflicts");

    console.log(store);
    store.load({
        callback: function(){
            console.log(store);
                store.removeAll();
                store.sync();
            console.log(store);
        }
    });

    console.log(store);
```

As you can see I added some console.log() to see what's in the Store. My Problem is that from the beginning (first console.log()) there is no data in the Store. But anyways, in my Grid I see about 170 items, which are in the Store and after clicking removve Button they disappear from the grid, but if I refresh the page they are there again.
I have also autoload and autosync property set to true. The output of console.log() stays the same all time. I tried with and without store.load() but there is always no data in the store I am going to empty.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've read the question a couple times, but I am still not sure what your question is? The provided code shows removing all records from a store on load... what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to clear the whole store. I added the load function to be sure all records, I wanted to delete are loaded, but still ran in trouble. Christophs' answer helped me in a way, but I have still some trouble, as you can see in the comment there below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store.removeAll() is known to not actually remove records but only to clear the store. Be carefull, this behavior changed with [later versions](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-removeAll)

You can use instead:

```
var store = Ext.getStore("Conflicts");

console.log(store);
store.load({
    callback: function(){
        console.log(store);
        store.remove(store.getRange());
        store.sync();
        console.log(store);
    }
});

console.log(store);
```

Comment: this works fine for deleting all Objetcts from the store, thats good. But if I reload the page it doesn't work anymore. I get Error in firebug "TypeError: id is undefined

if (id.isModel) {" I noticed by looking at the records with firebug that internalId was before page reload like "ext-record-230" and after reload just "230". Any ideas?

Comment: maybe also interesting if I open the webappsstore2 table in slite manager I see that extjs uses "undefined-(number)" as key, maybe there I already did a mistage so that extjs saves as undefined?

Comment: walk up the stacktrace on your exception. I think you are doing some invalid operation with your already deleted record.